# Arcgis field calculations, get last dits of number

Tags: vbscript, gis, tostring, arcgis

I want get 2 last digits of numbers, this digits also can be string not int

Cell:

29501864,071879
17906796,472795
17038547,962973
182638877,306748
101159098,3431
183391558,187717

VB script function: `Right(CStr( [tracts.Shape_Area] ),2)`

**What I get:**
94
47
32
48
31
17

**What I want get**
79
95
73
48
31
17

What is wrong in my function ?

Comment: Are you reading the shape_area correctly? If you're reading the field in the attribute table, sometimes it doesn't display all the trailing digits, so you may be getting the actual trailing digits, as opposed to the displayed ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is correct:

```
Right(CStr( [Shape_Area] ),2)
```

When you import a FeatureClass in a geodatabase, the `Shape_Area` created as a **Double** field that can have many decimal places! (By default 8 decimal places)

But in Attribute Table, you can see 6 decimal places by default. To see all the decimal places  of your numbers try this:

```
CStr( [Shape_Area] )
```